# Считать запись из файла

Tags: pascal

Требуется считать запись из файла (дано имя, фамилия, знак зодиака, дата рождения). Далее, записать данные в массив. Выдает ошибку

> 106: Invalid numeric format.

Код:

```
type
znak= record
name: string[18];
  zodiac: string[11];
  bday: array[1..3] of integer;
 end;
var
 book: array[1..8] of znak;
 fbook: file of znak;
 fi, fo: text;
 k,i,j: integer;
const
 zod_s: array[1..12] of string =
     ('capricorn','aquarius','pisces','aries','taurus','gemini','cancer','leo','virgo','libra','scorpio','sagittarius');

begin
assign(fi,'z4.dat');
 reset(fi);
assign(fo,'z4.res');
rewrite(fo);
for k:=1 to 8 do with book[k] do
read(fi,name,zodiac,bday[1],bday[2],bday[3]);
end.
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Пример файла приведите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ошибка часто бывает, когда в целочисленную переменную хотят записать строку или т.п.

Приведите пример файла, как уже раньше было сказано.